# Java Input/Output program that works with files

Tags: java, file, oop, input, output

So here's a code which reads input from the file

> date.in.txt

Then encrypts by doing the XOR operation between the k character from the text read from the file and the (k%n) character from the key, where is the key length. Then, it outputs it to

> date.out.txt

In the second part, it does the reverse, decrypts the text from

> date.out.txt

and outputs it to

> date.in.txt

Here's an example of the first part:

> date.in:  Hello World! How are you?
>
> date.out: 43 4 5 2 10 67 54 6 28 9 7 64 73 100 45 12 22 73 15 23 6 65
> 16 1 16 92

And here is one for the reverse:

> date.out.txt: 43 4 5 2 10 67 54 6 28 9 7 64 73 100 45 12 22 73 15 23 6 65
> 16 1 16 92
>
> date.in.txt: Hello World! How are you?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
        {Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        File file = new File("date.in.txt");
        File file2 = new File("date.out.txt");
        
        
        String [] s= new String[100];
        String S= new String();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            s[i]=new String();
        int nr=0;
        
        
        int vec[]=new int[100];
        int nrvec=0;
        
        
        String cuv;
        System.out.print("Enter key: ");
        cuv=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        int n=cuv.length();
        
        
        try 
            { Scanner input = new Scanner( file );
                while(input.hasNextLine())
                    { s[nr++]=input.nextLine();
                    s[nr++]="\n";} }
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
            { System.out.printf("ERROR: %s!\n", ex); }
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<nr;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<s[i].length();j++)
                { vec[nrvec++]=s[i].codePointAt(j); }
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<nrvec;i++)
            { int d=cuv.codePointAt(i%n);
            vec[i]=vec[i] ^ d; }
            
        
        nrvec--;
      
        
         try 
            { PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file2);
            for(int i=0;i<nrvec;i++)
                output.print(vec[i]+" ");
            output.close(); } 
    
         catch (IOException ex) 
            { System.out.printf("ERROR: %s!\n", ex); }
        
        
         int ok=1; // SECOND PART
         if(ok==1)
            {System.out.print("Enter key: ");
            cuv=scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\n");
            n=cuv.length();
            
            File file3 = new File("date.out.txt");
            File file4 = new File("date.in.txt");
            
            nrvec=0;
            
            try 
                { Scanner input = new Scanner( file3 );
                    while(input.hasNext())
                        { vec[nrvec++]=input.nextInt(); } }
                        
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
                { System.out.printf("ERROR: %s!\n", ex); }
         
            int e;
            try 
                { PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file4);
                for(int i=0;i<nrvec;i++)
                    { e=cuv.codePointAt(i%n);
                    output.print(vec[i]^e +" ");}  // 93
                output.close(); } 
    
            catch (IOException ex) 
                { System.out.printf("ERROR: %s!\n", ex); }
         
        
            }}}
```

The problem is that I get an error on line 93, that says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problem:      The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) int,
> String
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:93)

And I don't know why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the line at 93 to:

> output.print((vec[i]^e) +" ");}

The problem you had was with precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Write that line as

```
 output.print((vec[i]^e) +" ");}  // 93
```

Note the parentheses. Without them, the original code is effectively being treated as

```
 output.print(vec[i]^ (e +" "));}  // 93
```

since the "+" operator has higher precedence than "^".